# Conditional logic inside a django template {% with tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to do something like this inside my django template.

```
{% with url="http://"|add:sitePrefix|add:".com/post/?fromQuoteEmail=1&utm_source=c1&utm_medium=email{% if emailEventId %}&emailEventId={{ emailEventId }}{% endif %}{% if loginKeyObj %}&loginkey={{ loginKeyObj.keyword }}{% endif %}" %}
```

I am not sure how to get the conditional:

```
{% if emailEventId %}&emailEventId={{ emailEventId }}{% endif %}{% if loginKeyObj %}&loginkey={{ loginKeyObj.keyword }}{% endif %}
```

to play nice with my {%with tag

Thanks for your help!

Comment: using custom templatetag could resolve this problem, and the code would be nicer. Why don't you use custom templatetag?

Comment: @Sasa thanks that is a much better way to do it!